# Apache Failed to Start - Trying to find key for HTTP site

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https

I have a LAMP server with HTTP sites on 80 and HTTPS sites on 443.  Upon trying to start Apache, I am getting these errors:

```
[Tue Jun 05 13:15:36.179316 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3100] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for blah.site.us:80
[Tue Jun 05 13:15:36.179386 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3100] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Tue Jun 05 13:15:36.179391 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3100] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

It's trying to find a certificate/key pair for a site that should not be using SSL (ie, this error would make sense if this were one of my 443 sites and it couldn't find the key, but it shouldn't even be looking for a cert/key for the :80 sites).

Where is Apache being told that it should try to apply SSL to this site?  I've got "Listen 443 https" in my ssl.conf and my vhosts look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName some.example.com
   DocumentRoot /correctpath
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName secured.example.com
   DocumentRoot /correctpath
   SSLEngine on 
   SSLCertificateFile /correctpath
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /correctpath
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Make sure you have no `SSLEngine on` elsewhere, including in the `default` configuration file. Try by dichotomy, comment all `VirtualHost` blocks but one, run Apache, see if it starts, if yes go next step by uncommenting another `VirtualHost`, if no you have found which `VirtualHost` triggers the error.

Comment: My guess is that your abstracted configuration has abstracted too much away from your actual configuration, i.e. that your actual configuration includes a problem which is not visible in the abstracted one. Hard to point out the actual error without having the actual config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was ultimately due to having some vhost pairs, with a *:80 vhost for the http site and a corresponding *:443 vhosts for the same site that just served to redirect https to http.  I added "SSLEngine off" to the *:443 redirect vhosts, and the SSL mod stopped looking for certs/keys for the matching *:80 sites.  (Removing the *:443 redirect hosts also works and allows Apache to start, but then that redirect is gone, too.)